# Microsoft graph login data not cleared after browser clear data

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft Graph login in my chrome extension and I am facing a disturbing issue, seems that the user login info is not cleared even if I fully clear browser data, its only forgotten after I restart the browser.

Is this a security vulnerability ?
How is this even possible as my extension is closed and all data is cleared , where is this info saved ?
( I am aware of the logout api, the reason I am asking is because this seems like a security issue to me )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jacob. Could you please verify the known issue for the Microsoft Graph and here is the URL:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues

you can also verify the Content Security Policy (CSP) for the chrome extensions. Please verify the content scripts of the Chrome extension and make sure you know the chrome limitations.

Content scripts are JavaScript files that run in the context of web pages. By using the standardDocument Object Model (DOM), they can read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to them.

Here are some examples of what content scripts can do:
Find unlinked URLs in web pages and convert them into hyperlinks
Increase the font size to make text more legible
Find and process microformat data in the DOM
However, content scripts have some limitations. **They cannot:
Use chrome.* APIs, with the exception of:
extension ( getURL , inIncognitoContext , lastError , onRequest ,sendRequest )
i18n
runtime ( connect , getManifest , getURL , id , onConnect , onMessage , sendMessage )
storage**
Use variables or functions defined by their extension’s pages
Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

These limitations are for Content scripts can indirectly use the chrome.* APIs, get access to extension data, and request extension actions by exchangingmessages with their parent extension. Content scripts can also make cross-site XMLHttpRequests to the same sites as their parent extensions, and they cancommunicate with web pages using the shared DOM. For more insight into what content scripts can and can’t do, learn about the execution environment.

Please share the log file for further investigations.